# State-of-the-art symbolic algorithms for limits

Tags: limits, algorithms, asymptotics, computer-algebra-systems, symbolic-computation

I'm currently looking into the formalisation of limit-finding algorithms in a theorem prover, particularly exp-log-functions.

I found it very difficult to find information about what techniques modern CASs use for this. There is [Dominik Gruntz's thesis](https://e-collection.library.ethz.ch/eserv/eth:40284/eth-40284-02.pdf) and the book [Symbolic Asymptotics by John Shackell](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540210979) – the idea in both cases seems to be to find an asymptotic expansion of the form

$$f(x) \sim \sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty c_i(x)\omega(x)^{e_i}$$

where the real exponents $e_i$ are strictly increasing and $\omega$ goes to $0$ very quickly in a way that dominates the $c_i$. Therefore, one can determine the limit by looking at the first term for which $c_i$ is non-zero. The approach works because constructing these asymptotic expansions is compositional.

My question is now: Is this still the state-of-the-art approach? Is it what real-life CASs actually use? Is there any more recent literature about these things?

Comment: Mathematica used heuristics (I tried some tricky examples in the mid 90s and it failed) but now seems to rely on Gruntz's method ([according to a MMA kernel developer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134802/8688#comment363778_134802)). Gruntz used Maple and [SymPy also uses Gruntz's method](https://peerj.com/articles/cs-103/).